# Stored procedure passing parameter MAX size Limite

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, report

I'm Using Microsoft SQL server 2005

I Created stored procedure for generate the report.

ASP.NET from is used for passing parameter for the stored procedure.

Problem is it's not taking All the PartNumber what selected for parameter. It's taking ONLY 225 PartNumber and generate report for only those partNumber but in real I have more than 700 PartNumber.

### IS there any other way where I can extend the size for parameter.?

### Is there more size limit in sql server 2008.?

### Is there any way to store this  "@sqlQuery nvarchar(4000)" variable to XML variable.?

4000 is the max Size for nvarchar (because I tried to extend it and it's not accept more than 4000). Xml variable has no limit.

### Example for Parameter values (Passed From ASP.NET )

```
PartNumber
314013        
314039       
314047        
314054     
314062        
314070      
314088         
314096         
314104       
314344        
314351    
314377        
314393
```

### Stored procedure

```
USE [Reportbox]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateReport2]

(@prod nvarchar(4000))

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(4000)
declare @intMonth nvarchar(2)
declare @intMonth1 nvarchar(2)
declare @intMonth2 nvarchar(2)
declare @intMonth3 nvarchar(2)
declare @intMonth4 nvarchar(2)
declare @intMonth5 nvarchar(2)

SELECT @intMonth = fiscalmonth FROM FiscalWeeks WHERE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) between weekstart and weekend
if @intmonth-1<=0 BEGIN set @intmonth1=@intmonth-1+12 END else set @intMonth1=@intMonth-1
if @intmonth-2<=0 BEGIN set @intmonth2=@intmonth-2+12 END else set @intmonth2=@intmonth-2
if @intmonth-3<=0 BEGIN set @intmonth3=@intmonth-3+12 END else set @intmonth3=@intmonth-3
if @intmonth-4<=0 BEGIN set @intmonth4=@intmonth-4+12 END else set @intmonth4=@intmonth-4
if @intmonth-5<=0 BEGIN set @intmonth5=@intmonth-5+12 END else set @intmonth5=@intmonth-5

Set @sqlQuery =
'select distinct d.PROD80, DESC80, SUM_AVGU80, AVGU80, SUM_ONHA80, d.ONHA80, SUM_SAFE80, d.SAFE80,
MAX_FOQT80, MAX_ABCC80, MAX_MINQ80,
SUM_WEEK_NO_PO, SUM_TRIG80, d.TRIG80, SUM_BQTY80, DQTY80, OQTY80,
CASE WHEN d.AVGU80<>0 THEN CAST(ROUND(d.ONHA80/d.AVGU80,0) AS INT) ELSE 0 END AS WKS30
FROM DI80ACT00 d INNER JOIN vwDataAtCompanyLevel v on (d.prod80=v.prod80)
LEFT OUTER JOIN DI80ACT01 t on (d.prod80=t.prod80) and t.ware80 <> ''30''
WHERE  d.prod80 in (' + @prod + ') and d.prod80<>''HLW54B'' and d.ware80=''30''
GROUP BY  d.PROD80, DESC80, SUM_AVGU80, AVGU80, SUM_ONHA80, d.ONHA80, SUM_SAFE80, d.SAFE80,
MAX_FOQT80, MAX_ABCC80, MAX_MINQ80,SUM_HSTA80,SUM_HSTB80,SUM_HSTC80,SUM_HSTD80,SUM_HSTE80,SUM_HSTF80,SUM_POOR80,POOR80,SUM_TWIN80,SUM_WEEK_No_PO,SUM_TRIG80,TRIG80,SUM_BQTY80,DQTY80,OQTY80'

exec(@sqlQuery)
END
```

Any Help Or details will be very helpful
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which supports over 1 billion characters. However I don't really expect your `IN()` query against 700 values to perform very well at all.

If they choose `ALL` then pass the string `'ALL'` to the parameter, and only include the `IN()` list when they *haven't* selected `ALL`. So in the SQL:

```
Set @sqlQuery = 'select distinct 
...
WHERE d.prod80<>''HLW54B'' and d.ware80=''30'''
+ CASE WHEN @prod = 'ALL' THEN '' ELSE 
'AND d.prod80 in (' + @prod + ')' END
+ 'GROUP BY ...'
```

There is no reason to have a massive `IN()` clause that lists every single value in the table.

Comment: Hard to visualize what you "tried Already"... did you change both the `@prod` parameter ***AND*** the `@sqlQuery` variable?

Comment: Also, is this *all* of the part numbers? Or is a user really clicking and selecting 700 different part numbers and leaving some out?

Comment: User can Select Whatever PartNumber They want.

Comment: User Have select ALL option

Comment: Max Part Number selection Can be More Then 700

Comment: If they have a SELECT ALL option, then when they've chosen that option, leave the IN clause out of your dynamic SQL in the first place.

Comment: @krishkim you need to be a lot more specific than that. What exactly did you try, and what exact error message did you get?

Comment: I Modified query terms of you said.

Comment: This is The error In the report "An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for data set 'spCreateReport2'.
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors "